# PHP + Mongodb concat function throwing erros

Tags: php, mongodb, concatenation

Mongodb + php : I am very new to mongodb, Here my requirement is that I need to keyword search on two fields (i.e first_name, last_name) and return exact matched records as username in single query.

code:

```
$res = $this->db->nf_users->aggregate({$project:{username:{$concat:["$first_name","$last_name"]}}},
                  {$match:{username:$search}}
```

Which encountered with the errors.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `{` in

Can anybody suggest, where it went wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate(
{
   $project:{
      username:{ $concat:["$first_name",' ',"$last_name"]}
   }
},
{
  $match :{
     username: { $regex:"abc",$options:"i"}
  }
}
)
```

By this you will be able to make case insensitive search

```
$users = $this->db->collection('nf_users')
          ->raw(function ($collection) {
              return $collection->aggregate(
                 array(
                    array(
                       '$project' => array(
                            'username' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                         )
                      ),
                    array(
                        '$match' => array(
                             'username' => array('$regex' => 'avi', '$options' => 'i'),
                             )
                          )
                      )
                    );
                });
```

Comment: Thnq Somnath for quick response, But I am still encounter with that parse error.

Comment: $this->db->nf_users->aggregate(
       {
          $project:{
          username:{ $concat:["$first_name",' ',"$last_name"]}
          }
       },
       {
         $match :{
         username: { $regex: $search,$options:"i"}
         }
       }
       );

Comment: @SunilKumar: Updated answer. I don't know which mongo library you are using. I changed with raw query. It works well. Keep mongo variable in single quotes and PHP variables in double quotes.

Comment: $this->mC = new MongoClient();
$this->db = $this->mC->dbname; 

I am not sure, this is the object creation for our project, apart we are not using any api,

Comment: Thnq Somanath, I made the changes with your code, It perfectly working fine. Thanking you so much.
 $collection->aggregate(array( array('$project' => array( 'username' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$last_name')),          )
                      ),
                    array(
                        '$match' => array(
                             'username' => array('$regex' => $search, '$options' => 'i'),
                             )
                          )
                      )
                    );